# Alternative to Laravel collection's only() and intersect() methods

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5

`$request`
`{ "input1":"50" , "input2":"0" , "input3":"60000" }`

`$validkeys`
`{ "input1" , "input2" , "input3", "input4", "input5" }`

`$request->only($validkeys)`
[ extra keys can change earlier values to null]
`{ "input1":"50" , "input2":"0" , "input3":"60000"  , "input4":null , "input5":null }`

`$request->intersect($validkeys)`    [ removes key with value as `0`]
`{ "input1":"50"  , "input3":"60000" }`

All I want is `$request` with validation.

Comment: Could you elaborate what's your problem and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want  `$request` without invalid fields like "input6..7..8"  but I want keys with 0 values which are removed by `intersect` . I don't want extra keys from `only()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is shorter.
`$validated = array_intersect_key($request->all(), array_flip($validkeys));`

Answer (score 1):

This could probably help in your case. This code gets request keys using Request `only` method, then puts it into collection, filters it using `$value !== null` so the `0` should still be there.

```
// Put request values into collection
$valid = collect($request->only('input1', 'input2', 'input3'));

// Filter values
$valid = $valid->filter(function ($value) {
    return $value !== null;
});

// We get it back as an array
$valid = $valid->all();
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Kindly check my solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is:

```
$requestValidKeys = $request->keys()->intersect($validkeys);
$requestValid = $request->only($requestValidKeys);
```

So basically you only intersect the keys. And with these valid keys you call `only()`.

Comment: Got `Method keys does not exist.`  I am using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: `$request` has to be a collection. So maybe you have to use `collect($request)->keys()`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-keys

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to filter the `$request` using collections, which can make this read a little more clearly than array flipping/intersecting:

```
collect($request->all())->filter(function ($_, $key) {
    return collect($validKeys)->contains($key);
});
```